# SQLite show data assigned to table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm making an Android application that remembers `CountDownTimer` values (something like best score). I already built an SQLite database that stores values. But now I want to create a new activity (something like login activity) where user sign their name, then `CountDownTimer` activity opens with only this user scores.

Comment: That sounds pretty broad, and you haven't really asked a question. Can you narrow down and clarify your question? Please read [ask].

Comment: So user in my app can create his own profile with password and login. lets say there will be many profiles on device. Now i want to let user login to his profile and see his own countdowntimer values or chronometer values etc.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. You're telling us what you want to do, and it sounds very broad. Did you read [ask] like I suggested?

Comment: So here's my question, where can i get information about how to do this? or what are "key-words" because i cant find it in SQLite docs. Sadly no i didn't read it, but im going to do this right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the activity you extract the data from the database via a Cursor created by querying the database. You then populate the respective View or Views with the extracted data.

Assuming your database has a table named *timervalues* with 2 columns named cdt_value and userid, then the code to extract the data could be along the lines of :-

```
    Cursor csr = db.query("timervalues",null,"userid=?",new String[]{Long.toString(userid_to_find)},null,null,null);
```

You can then retrieve the data from the cursor with something like the following:-

```
    long[] scores = new long[csr.getCount];
    while (csr.moveToNext) {
        scores[csr.getPosition] = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("cdt_value");

    }
    csr.close();
```

So if you had a TextView with it's id set as **tv_score** and you wanted to display the first score then you could use :-

```
    this.findViewById(R.id.tv_score).setText(Long.toString(scores[0]));
```

---

If you wanted to display the scores as a list, using a ListView, then you wouldn't use an array of longs you'd use an array of objects (you could use Long) or you'd use the Cursor directly.

So assuming you have a ListView with it's id set to **lv_scorelist** then you could use :-

```
    ListView scorelist = this.findViewById(R.id.lv_scorelist);
    Cursor csr = db.query("timervalues",null,"userid=?",new String[]{Long.toString(userid_to_find)},null,null,null);
    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,csr,new String[]{"cdt_value"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
    scorelist.setAdapter(sca);
```

---

### Notes

- For a Cursor Adapter a column named **`_id`** must exist, this could be achieved (if the table timervalues was not defined with `WITHOUT ROWID`) by using "rowid AS _id, *" instead of null as the 2nd parameter to the `query` method when extracting the cursor so instead of

  - `Cursor csr = db.query("timervalues",null,"userid=?",new String[]{Long.toString(userid_to_find)},null,null,null);`
  - it could be
  - `Cursor csr = db.query("timervalues","rowid AS _id,*","userid=?",new String[]{Long.toString(userid_to_find)},null,null,null);`